# gnuplot - Colored tic marks

Tags: gnuplot

Is there any way to have `gnuplot` color the tic marks in the x and/or y axis? I'm using a background `png` file which is quite dark and I'd like the inner tics to show in white over it, not the default black.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `tics` seem to inherit their color from the `border`:

```
set style line 50 lt 1 lc rgb "red" lw 2
set border ls 50
plot sin(x)
```

The tic labels get their color from the `textcolor` option of `tics`:

```
set tics textcolor rgb "red"
```

*(The string "white" should work too, but that wouldn't look very nice in my demonstration since my background is white).*

There is no way to change just the tic-color.  However, if you want, you can change the tic/border color and then add a new border on top:

```
set arrow from graph 0,graph 1 to graph 1,graph 1 nohead ls -1 lc rgb "black" front
set arrow from graph 1,graph 1 to graph 1,graph 0 nohead ls -1 lc rgb "black" front
set arrow from graph 1,graph 0 to graph 0,graph 0 nohead ls -1 lc rgb "black" front
set arrow from graph 0,graph 0 to graph 0,graph 1 nohead ls -1 lc rgb "black" front
```

Comment: As a side note, specifying colors by `#RRGGBB` is probably slightly more system independent.  Red = `#ff0000`, white = `#ffffff` ... (although red and white should be recognized almost everywhere)

Comment: The problem with this is twofold: 1- Apparently I can't make the tics white without making the whole border white? 2- The second line that should set the color for the tic labels (ie: the numbers) does not work. The numbers inherit the color of the tics no matter what color I set there.

Comment: Scratch the second point, that's incorrect. But the first point remains: can I make **just the tics** white and not the whole border of the graphic?

Comment: @Gabriel -- Nope.  You can however, draw your own border with "arrows" over top of the white one.  I'll update.

Comment: I see. Could you clarify a bit what the first 2 lines in your answer do?

Comment: `set style line 50 ...` creates a new linestyle.  It uses linetype (lt) 1 which is typically solid, line color (lc) red and linewidth (lw) 2 (which means 2x the normal width).  That linestyle is tagged by gnuplot as line-style 50.  So, when I use the second line (`set border ls 50`), it says to plot the border using linestyle 50 (which is the one I just defined).

Comment: Excellent!! Man at this point I feel like I should you be paying you something :)

Comment: @Gabriel -- I use gnuplot **a lot**.  It's in my best interest to have lots of other people using it too because then it's development won't stop.  Plus, I like being top-dog on the gnuplot tag around here ;-).  It makes me feel like I'm an expert in something.

Comment: Well it's not just your feeling, I can definitely say you are an expert in `gnuplot`. Thanks again! Cheers.

Comment: @mgilson Suppose I want to have different colors for `y1` and `y2`. Mission impossible?

Comment: @Bernhard you can separately `set ytics` and `set y2tics`.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst this post is quite old, I though I'd offer my 2cents because I have a valid addition to the above.

If you immediately follow the set border command with unset border, then the colour of the tics & their labels remains in the colour you set, and the border just gets removed. For example,

```
set border linecolor rgb "gray75"
unset border
```

This way, you can at least change the colour of the tics & their labels (here, off-white), & your background remains dark & untainted by an unsightly (off-white) border, which is what the OP asked for?

Thus, no need to manually redraw the border in the previous answer. Still, the best answer above was useful to me so I will uptick!