# Set different Color for Tics on SAME Axes

Tags: colors, gnuplot

Is it possible to use different coloured or styled tics on the same axes.

tics: `0,1,1.5,2` and I want the `0` and the `2` colored `red` or `bold`.

Would be great for `multiplots` where have plots regarding the same measurements and you want to mark the y or x range in the different plot without overloading it to much. the alternative for me right now is to explicitly write the range on the y axes but it would be smoother with a solution for my question. I checked `mxtics`but from my experience it is not possible to set different colors for `major`and `minor`tics. But maybe I missed something.

Comment: You could cheat and use appropriately formatted arrows.

Comment: o I need to look into that thanks... so what you're saying is there is no 'gnuplot wanted' way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I mean in my comment:

```
set style arrow 1 nohead linecolor rgb "red" linewidth 2
set xtics pi format "%.0P"
set arrow 1 from -1.5*pi,-.38 to -1.5*pi,-.4 as 1
set arrow 2 from 1.5*pi,-.38 to 1.5*pi,-.4 as 1
plot [-4*pi:4*pi] sin(x)/x
```

yields

[image]